# XAML Binding type detection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, type-deduction

How does WPF(XAML) Binding-Type detection work? Is this done by using `Reflection`?

For example if I bind a `TextBox` to the following property:

```
public int Value
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

How does it check which type it is?

Thank you very much!

EDIT

This seems to be the relevant parts: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Markup/XamlTypeMapper.cs,5a164a14a9e585cf
and http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Markup/XamlTypeMapper.cs,f32e4963c50ad683

Comment: By Reflection, yes.

Comment: @Clemens are parts of this open-source so that I can take a look at it? Thank you for answer!

Comment: Get JetBrains dotPeek to decompile any of the WPF assemblies.

Comment: Or take a look at the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: @Clemens thanks a lot! Is it in general possible to contribute to this? For example for better dynamic support?